# Where should a point be located at a line so that the difference of distances of two other points lying on same side of the line from it is maximised?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, maxima-minima, coordinate-systems

> There is a line $L$ and two points $A$ and $B$ not lying on it. The points are on the same side of line. A point $C$ is located on the line $L$ such that $|AC - BC|$ is maximised. Determine $C$.

This question was originally asked in a coordinate geometry problem. However, I've ignored numerical values to focus on approach only instead of solution to a particular textbook question.

**My approach:**

Consider the triangle $∆ABC$. We know that :

$$AC - BC < AB$$

I thought above constraint as the desired maximum value and answered that the maximum value is $AB$. Also, it matched with answer key.

**Problem:**

The above inequality is strict and does not turn into an equality. If we were to equate them, then the triangle wouldn't exist and $ABC$ would become a line, thus rendering the concept of restraint meaningless.

So, why is my answer correct ( assuming answer key as correct) and how to explain this?

Are there any other and better methods to solve this problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: Your answer is correct: if point $C$ also lies on line $AB$ then $|AC-BC|=AB$, otherwise $|AC-BC|<AB$. Hence that is the position of $C$ giving the maximum.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Shouldn't this be edited as an answer?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca But what if $C$ lies on $AB$ but not between $A$ and $B$ ? How to make it rigourous or more clear ?Thanks very much.

Comment: Point $C$ cannot be between $A$ and $B$, because $A$ and $B$ are on the same side of line $L$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Yes but I am talking about the case when equality holds. Like you wrote, $AC - BC = AB$ . The equality holds when there is no triangle and hence no constraint, so how does it give maximum ?

Comment: It gives maximum exactly because in that case triangular inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca  If triangle inequality doesn't hold, then how do we know that it is giving us maximum value ? Sorry if I am not able to understand something very basic :(

Comment: Oops sorry ! I get it. Thanks very much.